# I need to show data from the database in a table in php and js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem with a page that contains js + php + mysql which in a tab I want to show the data of a mysql table and I have this code
when I try to change it to the one in the database, it doesn't show me if someone could help me through teamviewer or chat I would appreciate it

```
public function list ()
{
$ sql = "SELECT p.prespresmo, c.name as client, u.name as user, DATE (p.private) as date, p.monto, p.interes, p.saldo, p.formapago, DATE (p. fpago) as dated, p. deadline, DATE (p. deadline) as dated, p.
         FROM loans p INNER JOIN customers c ON
         p.idcliente = c.idcliente INNER JOIN users or ON
         p.user = u.userid ";
return run Query ($ sql);
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain what MySQL engine you're using, but I *think* there is a syntax error in your SQL query. You have `INNER JOIN users or ON`, I don't think you can use `or` there because it is a SQL reserved word.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your SQL Query